# How to make program using array in which user inputs number and program returns corresponding result

Tags: java, arrays

I have a school project in which the user will input a number and then the program displays what card corresponds to that number. I do not know how I should approach this project. Do I use arrays?

The project requires me to use a deck of cards as the contents of the array. 
The output of the program should be:

> Enter card number (1-52): 1 The card you picked is: Ace of Clubs.
>
> Enter Card Number (1-52): 11 The card you picked is Jack of Clubs
>
> Enter Card Number (1-52): 14 The card you picked is Ace of Diamonds
>
> Enter Card Number (1-52): 52 The card you picked is King of Spades

```
public class Deck {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList[][] table = new ArrayList[4][13];
    String[] suits= {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
    String[] ranks= {"Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack", "Queen","King"};

     for (int i=0; i<4; ++i) 
     for (int j=0; i<13; ++i) {

             }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The modulus operator comes in handy here:

```
String[] suits= { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };
String[] ranks= { "Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack", "Queen","King" };

for (int i=0; i < 52; ++i) {
    String suit = suits[i / 13];
    String rank = ranks[i % 13];

    System.out.println("Card: " + rank + " of " + suit);
}

Card: Ace of Clubs
Card: 2 of Clubs
Card: 3 of Clubs
Card: 4 of Clubs
...
Card: Jack of Spades
Card: Queen of Spades
Card: King of Spades
```

The trick here is that the index for the suit is determined by how many 13s we have already consumed.  This can be obtained by dividing the single index `i` by 13.  The rank can be determined as the remainder of the index divided by 13.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can solve it. Refer to the code comments for the explanations.

Code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] rank = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };
        String[] suit = { "Spades", "Hearts", "Diamond", "Clubs" };

        String[] cards = new String[52]; // Make a variable that will hold your deck of cards

        // This loop will make your deck of cards
        // "i" will serve as the iterator for all the cards in the deck of cards
        // "j" will serve as the iterator for the rank of the cards
        // "s" will serve as the iterator for the suit of the cards
        for (int i = 0, j = 0, s = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
            cards[i] = rank[j] + " of " + suit[s];
            j++;
            // Since each suit consist of 13 cards, you will then have to change the suit by
            // incrementing it, then you will have to set "j" to 0 so that the rank will
            // reset
            if (j == 13) {
                j = 0;
                s++;
            }
        }

        // Now that you have successfully generated your deck of cards you will then ask
        // the user for to pick a card

        // Use Scanner to get the user input
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // This try catch will be used to check if the user's input is invalid
        try {
            System.out.print("Enter card number (1-52): ");

            // retrieve the user's input
            int input = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
            input--; // since the array starts at index 0, you have to decrement the user input by 1

            // check if the input is in the range of 0 to 51 (since index starts at 0)
            if (input >= 0 && input <= 51) {
                System.out.print("The card you picked is: " + cards[input]);
            } else {
                System.out.println("You have entered an invalid input!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid input!");
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

}
```

Result:

```
Enter card number (1-52): 1
The card you picked is: Ace of Spades
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Deck {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] suits= {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
    String[] ranks= {"Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack", "Queen","King"};

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter card number (1-52)");
    int card_number = input.nextInt();      
    System.out.println("The card you picked is "+ranks[card_number/ 13]+ " of "+suits[card_number%13]);
}
}
```